# swift ios alpha numeric regex that allows underscores and dashes

Tags: ios, regex, swift, xcode

I am using this [lib](https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator) for validation and are trying to add my own regex.

What I want to do is to make a regex that allows alphanumeric A-Z 0-9 together with dashes and unserscores -_

I have tryed `let regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]"` but I cant get it to work.

I also want the regex to not only allow english letters, but all languishes.

The lib works cause I have made another regex that only allows ints 0-9 which works

```
let intRegex = "^[0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex look good but it will only match a single character. Do this `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$"` instead to match more than one character.

breakup --

`^` -- start of string

`[\pL0-9_-]` -- characters you want to allow

`*` -- any number of characters (the crucial bit you were missing)

`$` -- end of string

Comment: Thanks for explaining every bit!

Comment: But this will only accept english letters, is there a way to allow other eg: åäö ü etc ?

Comment: you can replace a-zA-Z with \pL to fix that. - `^[\pL0-9_-]*$`

Comment: If you want to allow a minus, you have to escape it (`\\-`) - at least in Swift 5 - otherwise it's seen as a range (like `0-9`) and it'll crash your app because it's an invalid range.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on @charsi's answer

```
extension String {
    var isAlphanumericDashUnderscore: Bool {
        get {
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$", options: .caseInsensitive)
            return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
        }
    }
}
```